# can someone help me to add astrict to javascript regex

Tags: regex

can someone help me to add *, &, (, ), to the following regex?

```
var r=/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9'\.,-]+$/;

if(!(r.test(search_key))){
    alert("Sorry, you have entered invalid characters, please try again.");     
    return false;
}
if(search_key =="Keyword(s)"){
    document.getElementById("field1").value = "";
}
if(search_city =="City, State or Zip"){                     
    document.getElementById("GH_search_field2").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var r=/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9'.,*&()-]+$/;
```

Having the `-` last is important, although you could also escape it with a backslash and put it anywhere.

Comment: And you don't need to escape the dot inside character class